# jQuery clone multiple times in to multiples elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm trying to clone an element multiple times. 
HTML is as follows

```
<html>
<div class="header">This is header</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="item-wrap">This is an item</div>
    <div class="item-wrap">This is an item</div>
    <div class="item-wrap">This is an item</div>
    <div class="item-wrap">This is an item</div>
    <div class="item-wrap">This is an item</div>
</div>
```

this is just an example code. inside `container` `div` there are many `item-wrap` `div` available and i'm trying to calculate full height of the `container` `div` and split it in to parts according height. and then clone `header` `div` before every split part.

here is the `jQuery` code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var viewportHeight = $(window).height();

var header = $('.header').clone();

var i = 0;
$(".item-wrap").each(function (index, domElement) {

    i += parseFloat($(this).outerHeight());

    if(i >= 300 && i < 350){
        $(this).addClass('clone1');
    }
    if(i >= 550 && i < 600){
        $(this).addClass('clone2');
    }
    if(i >= 800 && i < 850){
        $(this).addClass('clone3');
    }
});

$('.clone1').first().html(header);
$('.clone2').first().html(header);
$('.clone3').first().html(header);
</script>
```

The problem is it only do the last split. in this case it is `if(i >= 800 && i < 850)` First two splits doesn't clone the `header` `div`. please help. thanks!

Comment: can you post a plunker?

Comment: here is the actual code. https://codepen.io/dmmdust/pen/dZPOVX